# Generate N vectors of dimension D with average cosine similarity of Theta

Tags: matrix, vector, linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out a way to generate vectors that have some average cosine similarity with each other. From another question, I found how I can do this for a single vector. But I want the *average* cosine similarity of a set to be *Theta*.

Here's for a single vector:

```
import numpy as np


def rand_cos_sim(v, costheta):
    # Form the unit vector parallel to v:
    u = v / np.linalg.norm(v)

    # Pick a random vector:
    r = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros_like(v), np.eye(len(v)))

    # Form a vector perpendicular to v:
    uperp = r - r.dot(u)*u

    # Make it a unit vector:
    uperp = uperp / np.linalg.norm(uperp)

    # w is the linear combination of u and uperp with coefficients costheta
    # and sin(theta) = sqrt(1 - costheta**2), respectively:
    w = costheta*u + np.sqrt(1 - costheta**2)*uperp

    return w
```